# Html cgi printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n"); why must write \n\n?

Tags: html, cgi, special-characters, printf

I have a simple question for today:
what does exactly doing the **double** `\n` in  cgi programs fist line : `printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");`

Answer (score 3):

A blank line separates the HTTP Response Header from the HTTP Response Body.

Without one, there would be no way to know if the first line of the body was the body or another header.

HTTP uses `\r\n` not `\n` though. I recommend using a library to abstract away the details of CGI instead of doing it manually.

Comment: Can you give me an simple example ? My professor ask me that question and I wont to answer it with details! thanks you anyway!